# What do politicians do?

Tags: parties, political-theory, policy, political-system, political-science

I do not have much familiarity with politics other than being aware of how politicians are portrayed in the public, including a bunch of jokes made about them.

So, in reality, what do politicians do (and, does anyone know)?

Do politicians simply sometimes favor certain groups of people and their interests over others, perhaps allocating funds to given projects or causes, over others, or, do they do other stuff?

What are their roles?

Thanks.

Comment: A question directed at all politicians everywhere is probably too broad and unfocused to make it possible to provide the kind of concrete answer you seem to be looking for. Focusing in, for example, on what members of Congress do, or what a Governor of a state or a President, or a Mayor does, might be more fruitful.

Comment: if you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politician first, what questions remain?

Comment: @ohwilleke i think it would make the question hyperspecific and certainly would not make it clear to OP what the answer to their question is.  This isn't a question about specific function of a politician in any part of the government.  It's a question about politicians *as such*.  So a good answer should probably describe the delineation between political functions and public service and how politicians act as intermediaries between functions of their jobs and people who implement the details.  And probably what is the nature of a political struggle for power (political horse trading, etc.)

Comment: @ohwilleke and before people start closing this question as too broad and too vague, the question is not broad.  The author clearly stated the source of their confusion.  It may not be immediately clearly to people what the answer should be.  So the question should be protected.  But an answer should draw a good *general* picture of the nature of a politician's job rather than specific details of a role of a politician in any of the branches of the government.  This isn't a US-specific question, btw, at least it's not phrased that way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: "Politician" is a very vague category. There are lots of politicians in a lot of different positions in a lot of different countries with very different political cultures. You might want to focus this on a *specific* political position. Like "What does a member of the US Senate do during a typical work day?", "What are the duties of the Minister of Health, Labour and Welfare of Japan?" or "Can the Supreme Leader of Iran allocate funds to specific projects?".

Comment: @Philipp "politician" is a very general category, but it isn't vague.  When it comes to most people, asking whether or not they are professional politicians would be an easily-answered question.  I've made a few more points in a comment above.  I am not sure if you had a chance to read them, but I think this is only a vague question at first sight.  But in reality, it's a potentially good question and receive a very good answer about the nature of the job of a politician *as such*.

Answer (score 3):

Talking about a democracy, and generalizing from what I know from [germany](/questions/tagged/germany).

The great majority of politicians are **local**, they are **part-time,** and they are **unpaid or mostly unpaid.** I'm talking about town councillors, the heads of local party chapters, and so on. There are two roles, with significant overlap in the people who fill them:

**Elected Offices:**

When they are elected to a city council or the like, they will be paid a little for their work, but not enough to earn a living. In fact, if they do it right then the effective hourly rate might well be below minimum wages. Here is something for the German state of [Lower Saxony](https://www.mi.niedersachsen.de/download/172499), city councillors get a few hundred Euro per month.

- That means they need another job to pay their bills. It also means that what they do takes much of their "spare" time -- evenings, weekends, and so on.
- Their political role consists of controlling and directing the city administration. When it comes to things like welfare or taxes, the rules are set by the federal or state level and the supervision is done by the courts. But there are countless **administrative details to be decided.** And where and how priorities are set is a political decision:

  - Which roads are in need of refurbishment, and how much can the city afford?
  - Should there be a new bypass road? Many voters want good roads from where they are to where they need to be, but not passing their homes. [NIMBY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIMBY) politics.
  - Is the municipal garbage removal company working efficiently?
  - How many primary school students will there be ten years from now, and which school will get how many?
  - Will there be subsidies for the local museum, or will it have to rely on ticket sales?

The way to become a full-time politician is to get elected either as the mayor of a decent-sized town, or as a state legislator. Their salaries are good for a professional, even if they are lower than those of a business executive with similar responsibilities.

**Party Offices:**

Others work in the local and regional party chapters. That is usually not paid at all, except for a few part-time or full-time clerks at the district level party administration. Their role is threefold:

- They get to **campaign** and **explain** party politics to the voters. Standing at street corners, handing out leaflets. During election times, possibly going door to door talking to voters.
- Before the election, they **elect** candidates for the party. Most voters don't know and don't care just who their town councillors are. They don't know and don't care that some decisions are made on the municipal level, some at the state level, some at the federal level. They hold the party and their candidates responsible for anything any party representative has done or failed to do in the last decades (if not longer). So getting the party ticket is usually precondition to being elected, and politicking around likely successful candidacies can be intense and personal. Getting likely unsuccessful candidacies can be easier.
- They get to elect the party leadership, usually through the district to state and federal levels (and indirectly, on the European level). That could mean *electing* someone who *elects* someone who *elects* a party leader -- a big deal if that party leader is in position to become the head of government. (See the [Tory leadership election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Conservative_Party_leadership_election_(UK)) currently in the UK).
- (They also get to join writing the [election manifesto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifesto#Electoral_manifestos), but that tends to take second place to personnel decisions. Few people read a couple hundred pages per party.)

**Talking to People**

To do both of those things right, they spend a lot of time **listening** to people and answering (often inane) **questions**. Anybody who is reasonably coherent, non-threatening and polite will usually get a couple of minutes of their time, even if the politician in question is in no way responsible for the problem or the solution (see the point about municipal/state/federal issues above).

They also spend a lot of time **networking** both within and outside their party to find majorities for compromise deals -- *you support this endangered wetland, I support that factory*.